# How to stop firebase functions from propagating triggers

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, event-propagation

I have a Firebase function to decrease the commentCount when a comment is deleted, like this

```
export const onArticleCommentDeleted = functions.firestore.document('articles/{articleId}/comments/{uid}').onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
    return db.collection('articles').doc(context.params.articleId).update({
        commentCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
    })
})
```

I also have firebase functions to recursively delete comments of an article when it's deleted

```
export const onArticleDeleted = functions.firestore.document('articles/{id}').onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
    const commentsRef = db.collection('articles').doc(snapshot.id).collection('comments');
    db.recursiveDelete(commentsRef); // this triggers the onArticleCommentDeleted multiple times
})
```

When I delete an article, the onArticleCommentDeleted is triggered and it tries to update the article that **has already been deleted**. Of course I can check if the article exists before updating it. But it's really cumbersome and waste of resources.

Are there any ways to avoid from propagating further triggers?

Comment: Another way is to store the commentCount in another collection called article_aggregation with the same id. So when an article is deleted, the onArticleCommentDeleted update the document in article_aggregation instead of the articles collection. This avoid from updating non-existing article. But this leaves the trash documents in the article_aggregation. And it requires extra reading from corresponding article_aggregation for commentCount when you load an article.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem arises from the way I make use of the trigger. In general, it's not a good idea to implement an onDelete trigger on a child document updates its own parent. This will surely cause conflict.

Instead, at the client side, I use transaction

```
...
runTransaction(async trans => {
    trans.delete(commentRef);
    trans.update(articleRef, {
        commentCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
    })
})
```

This makes sure that if one of the operation fails they both fail, and eradicates the triggers. Relying to the client side is not the best idea, but I think we can consider the trade off.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent triggering the Cloud Function on the comments when you delete the comments for that article. You will have to check for that condition in the function code itself, as you already said.

Comment: If we have 100 comments, we have to check if the article exists 100 times despite we know 100% that it doesn't exist. That's unacceptable to me. What else can we do?